# Using QFileSystemModel along QTreeView and QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, structure, qtreewidget, qfilesystemmodel, qtreewidgetitem

I have a "project structure", which is something like this.

```
-Project Main File
--Project Subfile 1
--Project Subfile 2
--Project Subfolder 1
---Project Subfolder 2
----Project Subfile 3
```

I'm using a QFileSystemModel to get the files on the specified path. Then after recognizing what is a folder and what is a file i want to display them on a view with the structure from above.
What i've though is using a QTreeView using QTreeWidgetItem.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFileSystemModel` is a tree model. `QTreeWidget` is a tree *widget* which only accepts data ***in individual items***.

What you are looking for is the `QTreeView` widget, which accepts a `QAbstractItemModel` as its data structure. Use the `setModel()` function of `QTreeView` and pass it your `QFileSystemModel`.

For more info, see the [Dir View Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/itemviews-dirview.html). (Ignore the fact that it says it uses `QDirModel`, if you have the latest Qt SDK, it really uses `QFileSystemModel`).